# Paging fails at 10K items for /search on any site but Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2.2, search, paging

There's a problem with requesting more than 10,000 items.

- With Stack Overflow it works just fine.
- But with *Super User*, *Server Fault*, etc. no items are returned for requests for items after the 10,000th and `has_more` is erroneously set to `false`.
- It doesn't matter whether `page` and `pagesize` are both 100 or `page` is 200 and `pagesize` is 50.

For example, **this works**:
    [/2.2/search/excerpts?**page=199&pagesize=50**&q=security&site=serverfault](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/excerpts?page=199&pagesize=50&order=desc&sort=activity&q=security&site=serverfault)

and `has_more` is `true`.

But **this fails**:
    [/2.2/search/excerpts?**page=200&pagesize=50**&q=security&site=serverfault](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/excerpts?page=200&pagesize=50&order=desc&sort=activity&q=security&site=serverfault)

and `has_more` is (incorrectly) `false`.

Reference [this live site search](https://serverfault.com/search?q=%22security%22), which shows 28,846 questions that should match.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Confirmed. That's a bug and also applies to to all three `/search` routes and probably also to the `/similar` route.

Answer (score 2):

This was a search issue in elastic (`max_result_window`) that has now been tuned across the network.

See, also, [this related Q&A on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303174/no-more-than-10-000-results-are-visible-in-search).